# How to flatten comments using okular

Tags: pdf, okular

Recently Okular has become a great tool to annotate pdfs.

I have added some annotations (stamps) using okular to a pdf. I would like these annotations to become flat. By flat I mean that they are no longer selectable and deletable so that they are not distinguishable from the original pdf.

A Bug report has been filed on the [KDE bugtracking system](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383651).

Comment: Did you have any luck? I didn't find any way to do what you describe. Further, the stamp doesn't appear at all if I open the annotated pdf file in Firefox, Google Chrome or qpdf. (I tried the *File > Save As* route as well as the *Print to File* route.) I tried with both Kubuntu 18.04 and 19.04.

Comment: I meant `qpdfview`, not `qpdf`.

Comment: @DKBose No I had no luck. And you seem to be right. The annotations are not saved as pdf annotations, though I am sure they used to be saved correctly. Printing to pdf works for flattening other annotations but not for stamps.

Comment: I think a better place to file the bug would be https://bugs.kde.org.

Comment: @DKBose You are right. did so and updated my question.

Comment: I added back the Launchpad bug. I think there's nothing wrong in having both. But please rollback my edit if you disagree.

Comment: "Printing to pdf works for flattening other annotations" -- really? I created some text highlighting with Evince, and tried to print to PDF to flatten them, but printing with Evince and with Ocular discarded the highlighting.

Comment: @Alexey strange. I can not replicate this with okular. the highlighting gets printed and flat (the latter requires rasterization)

Comment: @Bruni, indeed, this only happens if the annotation is created in Evince. For annotations created in Okular the problem is different. Trying to flatten highlighted annotations with `pdftocairo` works neither for Evince, nor for Okular, but [in different ways](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/375#note_687351).

Answer (score 13):

Poppler PDF library can do this - Okular and Xournal++ use it internally.
The poppler-utils package comes with a pdftocairo utility. So the following is just another way to do it in the terminal instead of using a GUI application. Run the following command

```
pdftocairo -pdf "input.pdf" "output-with-flatten-annotations.pdf"
```

and your annotations will be flatten/"baked" into the PDF.

But as this more or less a PDF to PDF conversation, some differences may apply, e.g. Poppler considers your fontconfig resulting in font replacements and the internal structure of the PDF may be altered. Please be aware that using poppler-cairo in this context may result in larger PDF output files.

---

You might also want to try `qpdf` (another utility and package that is not poppler-related) as that utility does not do an entire PDF conversation.

```
$ qpdf --flatten-annotations=all input.pdf output.pdf
```

Please mind that there is also `print` and `screen` as argument value for `--flatten-annotations=` instead of `all` that includes both `print` and `screen`. Check `qpdf --help` for more information. As the output for help is pretty long, you might want to use a pager like `less`, e.g.

```
qpdf --help | less
```

Comment: This does not work. Text highlighting created in Evince is gone. Here is [what i experienced](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/375#note_687351).

Answer (score 4):

As this does not seem possible at the moment, a workaround is to use [xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp). 
In xournal:

- file--> annotate pdf, and then
- tools-->image select the signature
  file.